# I need to remove branches/if statement to improve pipelining: how to do it here?

Tags: c++, branch, pipeline

Heres my code:

```
inline void ScaleValue(double &value) {
    // bipolar
    if (!mIsBipolar) {
        value = (value + 1.0) / 2.0;
    }

    // amount
    value *= mAmount;
}
```

How would you optimize it removing branches/if? (I'm in a DSP context, I need to optimize as possible).

Comment: what is the type of `mIsBipolar`?

Comment: Its a bool. True or false. But I can switch to int 1/0 if it fit better (but I guess it is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mIsBipolar` is a `bool` then this

```
inline void ScaleValue(double &value) {
    value = mAmount * ((1+mIsBipolar)/2.0 * value + (1-mIsBipolar)/2.0);
```

should work exactly as your previous code.

When mIsBipolar is `false` then its `int` representation is 0, and so you have

```
value = mAmount * ((1+0)/2.0 * value + (1-0)/2.0);
```

when it is `true` then:

```
value = mAmount * ((1+1)/2.0 * value + (1-1)/2.0);
```

which is exactly your formula.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is removing the if and then you can (almost) always do as follows.

```
inline void ScaleValue(double &value) {
    value = mIsBipolar*value + !mIsBipolar*((value + 1.0) / 2.0)
    value *= mAmount;
}
```

if `mIsBipolar` is true then value keeps its original value `value = mIsBipolar*value`
otherwise it gets the value on the right hand side of the `+` sign `!mIsBipolar*((value + 1.0) / 2.0)`.